# How to simulate probability in Octave

Tags: octave, probability

My task is to simulate a signal with a binary message going through a noisy channel with a bit error rate of 1 in 1000. Here is what i have done.

```
function [r f] = generateBitError(d, ber)
  flag = false;
  if(randi(round(ber^(-1))) == 1)
    i = randi(length(d));
    d(i) = not(d(i));
    flag = true;
  endif
  
  r = d;
  f = flag;
endfunction
```

d is a matrix whose cells contain the binary digits and ber usually takes the value 10^(-3). It seems to work correctly in practice, but is this a valid way of simulating that 1 in 1000 bit error chance? Does randi have the same probability for all integers in the interval [1, 1000]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the main problem with this intepretation isn't necessarily using `randi` vs `rand`, or how reliable this is, but the fact that you are always guaranteeing that there will *never* be more than one errors in the signal, which is not a good assumption.

This is not what an error rate of 1:1000 typically means. It means that *each* bit has a 1:1000 chance of being flipped. I.e. each bit undergoes a bernoulli trial with a bernoulli parameter of 0.001. Flipping 2 or more bits in the whole signal should be entirely *possible*; it just shouldn't be very *probable*.

So I would rephrase this to something like this instead:

```
function [ OutputSignal, HasFlipped ] = apply_noise( InputSignal, mu = 0.001 )
   % InputSignal: A horizontal vector of 0 or 1 values
   % mu: Bernoulli parameter denoting probability of error event
   N = length( InputSignal );
   ErrorPositions = rand( 1, N ) <= mu;
   OutputSignal = InputSignal;
   OutputSignal( ErrorPositions ) = ~OutputSignal( ErrorPositions );
   HasFlipped = any( ErrorPositions );
end
```

Also, avoid meaningless variable names like r, f, d, ber and stuff. They make such code very hard to read, when in fact the logic of the code is simple. Your future self will be crying tears of gratitude in a month's time when you'll need to debug this code.